# How to setup Foundry in a sub directory of a monorepo?

Tags: foundry

I would like to setup a Foundry dev environment in a monorepo under a sub directory/folder, no the root directory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use the `--no-git` flag when using `forge`. For example, to setup a new project you can use:

```sh
forge init --no-git <project-name>
```

And to add a dependency you can use:

```sh
forge install --no-git <dependency>
```

If you're using VSCode you can also add the following setting to your `.vscode/settings.json` file:

```json
{
  "solidity.monoRepoSupport": true
}
```

This will make compatible the monorepo with the Solidity extension. More info [here](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity/issues/335#issuecomment-1507329460).